# what does these expression mean ? `${server Path}/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js`

Tags: javascript, testing, gulp

```
`${server Path}/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js`,
```

May i ask the above code, what does ** , * , | , * stand for ? 
what can i search for to read into this ?

Comment: That code on its own is just creating a string. In principle the string could be used for anything, but it is very likely that whatever other code is using this string plans to use it for pattern matching of files. In the context of pattern matching, `*` are wildcards that can match anything, `!` means 'not', `|` means 'or'.

Comment: I agree, but it looks more like pseudo code as `${server Path}` wouldn't validate properly. More like API instructions, or something from a README.

Comment: this is run within gulp, just curious how would gulp be able to understand these operators, and how those it run through my files, cause from my root folder it doesn't seem exactly accurate for some file directory but it could run lol. Thank you for your comments. it just confirmed my guesses as i couldnt find them from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like glob syntax to me:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

`*` matches everything apart from slashes, so it will match any file but it won't match subfolders.

`**` matches everything including slashes, so subfolders can be searched.

`|` is just OR.

`!` means NOT.